# Query reg msiexec silent install

Tags: wix, wix3.5, windows-installer

When we do msiexec.exe /i myApp.msi /q

I know we end up doing a silent installation, but from where does the installer get the values of the fields that have to be populated and are needed for the installation to happen. For instance, there may be a few fields or parameters like username, password, etc, which we might obtain from the user during a regular install.

In a silent install, the installer gets these from an input file. Where is this input file stored? or how does it get these values?

I am trying to do a silent install and am facing issues because it is picking up a wrong value for a particular attribute...which I dont how its picking up.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters you refer to are called "Properties" in the Windows Installer. So, if you run silently, the properties will have their default value. If you specify a value in a `Property` element that will be used. If you have `SetProperty` or other `CustomAction` elements those can change the value of the properties. You can also provide properties on the command-line to the install like so:

```
msiexec /i path\to\your.msi /q PROPERTY1=value PROPERTY2="my other value" PROPERTY3=2
```

It is also important to note that the Windows installer does not store property values that are changed during the install. You'll want to check out the [Remember Property Pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern) for that.

Answer (score 0):

MSI's do not natively use input files to get values.  If that's your story, you had to implement custom actions to make that happen.

Typically you'd use a Secure Custom Property  ( A public property that is listed in the SecureCustomProperties property where a public property is one that is in all CAPS. )  passed at the commandline.

```
msiexec /i foo.msi /qn USERNAME=Bob PASSWORD=1Password
```

Typically you'd have custom dialogs, controls and custom actions in the UI and Execute sequence to handle validation of the inputs.